# Get access to form controller validation errors in a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a directive that wraps a `form` element with some inputs. One of the options is passing in a `formName`. Usually, with a form with the example name of `myForm`, to show an error you would do something like `myForm.firstName.$error.required`.

But, how do I get access to the errors when the form name is dynamically being passed in to the directive?

**example usage**

```
<my-custom-form formName='myForm' formSubmit='parentCtrl.foo()'></my-custom-form>
```

**directive**

```
  angular.module('example')
    .directive('myCustomForm', [
      function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: 'myCustomForm.directive.html',
          scope: {
            fornName: '@',
            formSubmit: '&'
          },
          require: ['myCustomForm', 'form'],
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var directiveCtrl = ctrls[0];
            var formCtrl = ctrls[1];

            scope.data = {};

            scope.hasError = function(field) {
              // how do i show the errors here?
            };

            scope.onSubmit = function() {
              scope.formSubmit();
            };
          }
        };
      }]);
```

**template**

```
    <form name="{{ formName }}" ng-submit="onSubmit()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'is-invalid': hasError('fullName') }">
        <input type="text" name="fullName" ng-model="data.full_name" required />
        <div ng-show="hasError('fullName')">
          <p>How do I show this error?</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'is-invalid': hasError('email') }">
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="data.email" ng-minlength="4" required />
        <div ng-show="hasError('email')">
          <p>How do I show this error?</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem with your code is that the directive requires itself, I don't think that will work. Just removing the `myCustomForm` from the require works fine.

To check if the field has errors, you just need to check if the `$error` object in the form controller is empty.

```
  require: ['form'],
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
    var formCtrl = ctrls[0];

    scope.data = {};

    scope.hasError = function(field) {
      // Field has errors if $error is not an empty object
      return !angular.equals({}, formCtrl[field].$error);
    };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zPiFpwdXSO0rCkOldlv?p=preview)

Comment: This works within the `link` function, but how can I get access to the form name `myForm` within the view itself? So I could do something like `<div ng-show='myForm.lastName.$error'>show this</div>`?